# Why is my render coming out this way?

Tags: rendering, materials, objects, blender-internal-render-engine

So i've had some issues rendering my object. It seems to come out as a weird sheer type of color. No matter what i try to do nothing seems to work. I am guessing it has something to do with diffusion but not sure. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is too vague. Please upload your file to share it so someone could look into it. Also post an example effect you would like to achieve so we know where you wanna head for. Else no one knows what you really wanted and no one will be able to help you do that.

Comment: To me it looks like you have a point light between your characters feet, what you can see is within the area that the light extends.

Comment: First thought based on your description is Z fighting. This is where two meshes exist in the same location and Blender can not decide which mesh is in front of the other. Check for duplicate meshes, try hiding things to see it the effect goes away.